# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map<String,Object>> to Map<String,Object> JAVA & SELENIUM

Tags: java, list, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I need to loop **depending on the number of rows thrown by a given SQL SENTENCE** and assign the value of the column in every iteration

---

This is my CODE:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapHandler;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class assign_code{
    static Connection conn = null;
    static QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
    static boolean keepConnection = false;
    
    public static void createConn(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password) throws SQLException, IOException {

        if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
            String driver = null;
            DbUtils.loadDriver(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params) throws
    SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password);
            if (params == null) {
            return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler());
      } else {
          return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler(), params);
    }
     } catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     } finally {
    closeConn();
     }
   }
    
    
    public static void closeConn() throws SQLException {
        if (!keepConnection) {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, IOException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\SELENIUM\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    String urlString="jdbc:sqlserver://GERTER5404.btqw.local:1433;databaseName=Test";
    String usernameString="admin";
    String password="admin";
    String driverr="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String sqlQuery= "select APPROVERID from orders.Approvals where ITEMID = ?";
    
    Map<String,Object>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://stage.com/backend");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("12345678");
    driver.findElement(By.id("add_new_option_button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(resultSet.get("APPROVERID").toString());

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"save\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    
    }
}
```

---

Suppose that my SQL QUERY thrown **3 rows** after executing this:

SQL QUERY:

```
select APPROVERID from orders.Approvals where ITEMID = 45;
```

**Image:**

[image]

**I want to loop depending on the amount of rows thrown by the SQL QUERY and assign the value**

In first loop, I need to set the parameter APPROVERID within the value from row #1 and column #4

[image]

In the second loop, I need to set the parameter APPROVERID within the value from row #2 and column #4

[image]

In the THIRD loop, I need to set the parameter APPROVERID within the value from row #3 and column #4

[image]

---

I did this:

**A function called "getResultInMapList":**

```
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params) throws
    SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password);
            if (params == null) {
            return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler());
      } else {
          return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler(), params);
    }
     } catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     } finally {
    closeConn();
     }
   }
```

**Invoking the method:**

```
 String sqlQuery= "select APPROVERID from orders.WebOrderItem where itemid = ?"; 
    List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet=getResultInMapList(String url, String driver, String usr, String pwd,sqlQuery, "45"); 
        for (Map<String, Object> rows: resultSet) 
            { for (Map.Entry<String, Object> row: rows.entrySet()) 
                { driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).ssendKeys(resultSet.get("sku").toString()); } 
                
            }
```

I am having this message:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Am i looping alright?

---

EDIT #1:

I am having this error after using this sentence:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45");
```

[image]

> The method get(int) in the type List<Map<String,Object>> is not
> applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Declared

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params)`
```

and inside main method you are calling

```
Map<String,Object>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45")`
```

which is never declared. Hence the error

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!.
Yeah, you're right. Is the logic about "looping and assinging" the value correct? does it make sense?. Could you please tell me if i'm missing anything?

Comment: Yes the logic is correct but you may need to include clicking on Save inside the 2nd for loop as there is only one text box so what would happen is it would every time overwrite till last row then come out of the for loops and then save

Comment: Gonna check that out, pal

Comment: Pal, i am having this error on driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(resultSet.get("sku").toString()); after using this; List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45");

Error: The method get(int) in the type List<Map<String,Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: In List you cant access directly by key but by index. resultSet is a list and you are trying to access its element by key. hence i requested to use For loop where where you are iterrating through each map and in second for loop through each entry set in the map

Comment: What should i do in order to make it work?

Comment: pls refer prev comment. use for loop

Comment: if you want to use only one row then resultSet.get(0).get("sku")

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how to adapt a for loop there. I'm a little confused about for loops because previously i used 2 other loops. Could you please show me some code and clear my mind?

Comment: if you want to use only one column then jsut iterarte through rows as  for(int i=0;i<resultSet.size();i++){  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(resultSet.get(i).get("sku").toString());}

Comment: if you want to iterate through multiple rows and column then for (Map<String, Object> rows: resultSet) { for (Map.Entry<String, Object> row: rows.entrySet()) { driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(row.get("sku")); } }

Comment: Can i use"getResultInMapList" and this at the same time: for(int i=0;i<resultSet.size();i++){ driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(resultSet.get(i).get("sku").toString());}

Comment: yes and you need to assign the value to List<Map<String,Object>>resultSet

Comment: Could you please provide me an example when it is necessary to iterate through multiple rows and column? I don't get it at all.

Comment: When you have to fill multiple text boxes with different column value  multiple times saving it

Comment: If i have 3 rows BUT 1 column should i use: a) List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45"); or b) Map<String,Object>resultSet= getQueryResultInMap(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45");

Comment: You need to use a as you have multiple rows

Comment: Pal, could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954882/cannot-click-on-the-search-bar-from-grid-in-selenium-java

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because your method "*getResultInMapList*" is returning a List of Map (**List<Map<String,Object>>**) and you're trying to place those results into a single map Map<String, Object> instead in a List of Map.

I'm looking at the image at the end of your question, and in there, instead of:

```
Map<String, Object>resultSet=getResultInMapList(String url, String driver, String usr, String pwd,sqlQuery, "45");
```

You need to write:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet=getResultInMapList(String url, String driver, String usr, String pwd,sqlQuery, "45");
```

And that will fix your error.