# Cannot click on the search bar from grid in Selenium & JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, datagridview, grid

I have this search bar from a GRID:
[image]

That bar has this:

```
<input class="admin__control-text data-grid-search-control" type="text" data-bind="
                i18n: placeholder,
                attr: {
                    id: index,
                    placeholder: $t(placeholder)
                },
                textInput: inputValue,
                hasFocus: focused,
                keyboard: {
                    13: apply.bind($data, false),
                    27: cancel
                }" id="fulltext" placeholder="Search by keyword">
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="fulltext"]
```

I've tried different things but no one seems to work for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fulltext\"]")).sendKeys("9132A42H");
```

or even:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("9132A42H")).click();
```

What should i do?

---

I have added the HTML DOM

HTML DOM:

```
<html lang="es"><head><script> var BASE_URL = 'https://testing.test.com/backend/admin/index/index/key/b8574be62125963e01c2a6e44944a0c7f25ff01223a23e2ec0ccc66240a34e68/'; var FORM_KEY = '7nHtBRpYjWY028GP'; var require = { 'baseUrl': 'https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US' };</script> <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="title" content="Magento Admin">
<meta name="keywords" content="Company, B2B, Orders">
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<title>Magento Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_ReCaptchaUser/css/recaptcha.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Mageplaza_Core/js/help.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://testing.test.com/media/favicon/stores/1/CompanyIcon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://testing.test.com/media/favicon/stores/1/CompanyIcon.png">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="js/theme" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/js/theme.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/backend/bootstrap" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/backend/bootstrap.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/adminhtml/globals" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/adminhtml/globals.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Catalog/catalog/product" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Catalog/catalog/product.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Translation/js/mage-translation-dictionary" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Translation/js/mage-translation-dictionary.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="underscore" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/underscore.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/smart-keyboard-handler" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/smart-keyboard-handler.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/ie-class-fixer" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/ie-class-fixer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery/jquery.tabs" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="domReady" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/requirejs/domReady.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery/patches/jquery" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/patches/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/dataPost" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/dataPost.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/apply/main" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/apply/main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/backend/notification" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/backend/notification.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/mage" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/mage.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/translate" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/translate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="text" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/requirejs/text.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery/jquery-migrate" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery/ui" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="knockoutjs/knockout" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/knockoutjs/knockout.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="knockoutjs/knockout-es5" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/knockoutjs/knockout-es5.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/template" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/template.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/observable_array" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/observable_array.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/apply/scripts" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/apply/scripts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/observable_source" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/observable_source.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="knockoutjs/knockout-repeat" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/knockoutjs/knockout-repeat.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/resizable" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/resizable.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/scope" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/scope.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/range" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/range.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/keyboard" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/keyboard.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/optgroup" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/optgroup.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/autoselect" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/autoselect.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/outer_click" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/outer_click.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/fadeVisible" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/fadeVisible.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/collapsible" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/collapsible.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/staticChecked" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/staticChecked.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/simple-checked" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/simple-checked.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bind-html" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bind-html.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/tooltip" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/tooltip.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/color-picker" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/color-picker.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/wrapper" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/wrapper.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/storage/local" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/storage/local.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry-factory" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry-factory.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/formatter" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/formatter.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/message-pool" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/message-pool.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/levels-pool" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/levels-pool.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger-utils" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger-utils.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/main" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="spectrum" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="tinycolor" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/jquery/spectrum/tinycolor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="moment" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/moment.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/template" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/template.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/dom-observer" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/dom-observer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/bindings" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/bindings.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/arrays" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/arrays.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/compare" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/compare.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/misc" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/misc.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/objects" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/objects.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/utils/strings" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/utils/strings.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/loader_old" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/loader_old.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/backend/form" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/backend/form.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/backend/validation" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/mage/backend/validation.js"></script></head><body data-container="body" id="html-body" class="adminhtml-auth-login page-layout-admin-login"><section class="page-wrapper">    <script> require([ "jquery", "jquery/ui" ], function($){ $.extend(true, $, { calendarConfig: { dayNames: ["","","","","","",""], dayNamesMin: [".",".",".","",".",".",""], monthNames: ["","","","","","","","","","","",""], monthNamesShort: ["ene.","feb.","mar.","abr.","may.","jun.","jul.","ago.","sept.","oct.","nov.","dic."], infoTitle: "Sobre\u0020el\u0020calendario", firstDay: 1, closeText: "Cerrar", currentText: "Hoy", prevText: "Anterior", nextText: "Siguiente", weekHeader: "WK", timeText: "Tiempo", hourText: "Hora", minuteText: "Minuto", dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822, showOn: "button", showAnim: "", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, buttonImageOnly: null, buttonImage: null, showButtonPanel: true, showOtherMonths: true, showWeek: false, timeFormat: '', showTime: false, showHour: false, showMinute: false, serverTimezoneSeconds: 1664920254, serverTimezoneOffset: -10800, yearRange: '1922\u003A2122' } }); enUS = {"m":{"wide":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"abbr":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}}; });</script> <script>    require.config({
        map: {
            '*': {
                wysiwygAdapter: 'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter'
            }
        }
    });</script> <script> window.cookiesConfig = window.cookiesConfig || {}; window.cookiesConfig.secure = true; </script><header class="login-header">    <a href="https://testing.test.com/backend/admin/" data-edition="Enterprise" class="logo"><img class="logo-img" src="https://testing.test.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/US/images/magento-logo.svg" alt="Admin Panel" title="Admin Panel"></a> </header><div class="login-content"> <form method="post" action="" id="login-form" autocomplete="off"><fieldset class="admin__fieldset"><legend class="admin__legend"><span>Welcome</span></legend><br><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="7nHtBRpYjWY028GP"><div class="admin__field _required field-username"><label for="username" class="admin__field-label"><span>Nombre de usuario</span></label> <div class="admin__field-control"><input id="username" class="admin__control-text" type="text" name="login[username]" autofocus="" value="" data-validate="{required:true}" placeholder="nombre de usuario" autocomplete="off"></div></div><div class="admin__field _required field-password"><label for="login" class="admin__field-label"><span>password</span></label> <div class="admin__field-control"><input id="login" class="admin__control-text" type="password" name="login[password]" data-validate="{required:true}" value="" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off"></div></div> <div class="form-actions"> <div class="links"><a class="action-forgotpassword" href="https://testing.test.com/backend/admin/auth/forgotpassword/">Forget password?</a></div> <div class="actions"><button class="action-login action-primary"><span>Iniciar sesión</span></button></div></div></fieldset></form></div><footer class="login-footer"> <a class="link-copyright" href="http://magento.com" target="_blank" title="Magento"></a> Copyright © 2022 Magento Commerce Inc. All rights reserved.</footer></section></body></html>
```

Comment: can u pls provide page url or html dom

Comment: Hey @SonaliDas pal. It is not exposed at all

Comment: then pls provide html dom

Comment: How can i get the html dom? @SonaliDas

Comment: driver.getpagesource() and then copy the value it returns and paste it or you can provide little bit more node details than what you have posted.

Comment: @SonaliDas take a look, pal. I have edited my question